# Decoding ASN.1 to String and Passing to Get-DateTime

Tags: string, powershell, date

Using PowerShell, I'm trying to convert ASN.1 from a Certificate Revocation List's Next Publish extension to a Date-Time object using `System.Security.Cryptography.AsnEncodedData` to extract the date/time as a string; which I then planned to pass to `Get-DateTime`.  The object has a `Format` method which returns the decoded value as a string (according to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.asnencodeddata.format?view=netframework-4.8)).

In the snippet below the Base-64 ASN.1 value is taken from a *real* CRL.

```
$textDateTime = "31 May 2019 07:04:50"

$asnBase64 = "Fw0xOTA1MzEwNjA0NTBa"

# 1.3.6.1.4.1.311.21.4 is the OID for Next Update extension
$extAsnDecoded = New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.AsnEncodedData(
                    '1.3.6.1.4.1.311.21.4',
                    [System.Convert]::FromBase64String($asnBase64))

$nextUpdateString = $extAsnDecoded.format($false) # false for single line result

$textDateTime
$nextUpdateString

Get-Date $textDateTime
Get-Date $nextUpdateString
```

The above returns:

```
31 May 2019 07:04:50
‎31 ‎May ‎2019 07:04:50

31 May 2019 07:04:50
Cannot bind parameter 'Date'. Cannot convert value "‎31 ‎May ‎2019 07:04:50" to type "System.DateTime". Error: "String was not recognized as a va
lid DateTime."
At line:14 char:10
+ Get-Date $nextUpdateString
+          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Get-Date], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotConvertArgumentNoMessage,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetDateCommand
```

As you can see, the two variables *look* identical on screen. However, while the simple string variable converts to a `DateTime` with `Get-DateTime` the value (apparently a string) decoded from ASN.1 fails.  Using the `.GetType()` method on each shows they are both strings.

If I look at the contents of both as ASCII, I get strange results:

```
$enc = [system.Text.Encoding]::ASCII

$enc.GetBytes($textDateTime) -join ","
($enc.GetBytes($textDateTime) | foreach {[char]$_}) -join ""

$enc.GetBytes($nextUpdateString) -join ","
($enc.GetBytes($nextUpdateString) | foreach {[char]$_}) -join ""
```

I get:

```
51,49,32,77,97,121,32,50,48,49,57,32,48,55,58,48,52,58,53,48
31 May 2019 07:04:50
63,51,49,32,63,77,97,121,32,63,50,48,49,57,32,48,55,58,48,52,58,53,48
?31 ?May ?2019 07:04:50
```

As you can see, there are extra question marks (ASCII character 63) in the version returned by decoding the ASN.1; which may explain why `Get-DateTime` fails.

What's going on here?  More importantly, how can I get the string decoded from the ASN.1 to be a valid input to `Get-DateTime`?

Comment: use something like `-replace '[^a-z0-9 :]', ''` to get rid of the extended characters. i suspect you have something along the lines of a non-breaking space or other such character in there. if you want to get a better look at it, try piping to the `Format-Hex` cmdlet and then looking up the hex values for the extra, non-printing characters.

Comment: @Lee_Dailey - thanks.  I did consider something along that line, but thought it rather kludgy to be honest.  Saying that, if it's the only way then so be it.

Comment: yep, it's annoying. [*grin*] however, unless you can dig out the reason the decoding is stuffing in those extra characters ... you are stuck with symptom-fixing. i can't find any info on the crypto stuff you used & non-standard chars. [*sigh ...*]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The string returned by `AsnEncodedData.Format()` includes a bunch of Left-to-Right formatting characters. You can replace this with a simple regex:

```
$nextUpdateString = $extAsnDecoded.Format($false) -replace '\p{Cf}'
```

`Cf` is regex short-hand for the "Other, Format" unicode category, which will match (and remove) the formatting characters, after which you should be able to pass the string to `Get-Date`

Comment: Thank you. After encoding as UTF8 and applying the suggestion by @Lee_Dailey of piping through `Format-Hex` instead of my concoction, the output shows `E2808E` (left to right) as you say.  Presumably, the question mark was just a placeholder for a character which isn't in the ASCII table.